Search for text within a cell and returning unique value based on which word is found in the cell
Search for text within a cell and returning value based on what is found.  Hello, I need to amend this example formula so if cell C3 finds "apple" that the value $1 is returned, but if it finds "orange" that the value $2 is.
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",C3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",C3))),"1","")

I've gotten errors trying to make this an if/then for finding apple as text vs. orange as text in the cell C3.

The direct solution is to use the IFS function:
=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",C3)),"$1",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange",C3)),"$2",TRUE,"")

More sophisticated way is
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"apple","orange"},C3)),{"$1","$2"},"")

or
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"apple","orange"},C3)),{"$1","$2"},""))

Just add required values in both arrays to extend the number of pairs.
Credits to @MayukhBhattacharya. In real apps it would be better to use a dedicated range/worksheet to supply pairs:

[C7]=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Dedicated!$A$2:$A$3,C3)),Dedicated!$B$2:$B$3,"")


Using XLOOKUP() is better, also suggested to use a table of reference for the search key words, it will dynamic and hence no hardcoding, which will user in future to add more key words. Both the lookup_array and return array keep aside.

If you want to stick with the original IF() statement, then you need a nested if statement.

If you find "apple" then you get $1, but you stop there (without looking for "orange").
If no "apple", then if you find "orange" you get $2.
If neither is found, you get something else (I put "{no apple or orange}" in the example).

Here's an example of that nested if statement:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",C3)), "$1", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange",C3)), "$2", "{no apple or orange}"))


*Or is it supposed to be looking for both words, and then returning $1 if only one of them was found (apple or orange), and $2 if both of them were found? It's not clear...
